# polyfills.bundle.js:5021 GET http://localhost:8080/checkUser?username=test2 401

Tags: web-services, spring-boot, angular5

I got this error while trying to implement web service that check if the user exist from his name:

```
polyfills.bundle.js:5021 GET http://localhost:8080/checkUser?username=test2 401 ()

ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/checkUser?username=test2", ok: false, …}
```

this is my code:
 serviceImpl.java

```
@Override
    public User checkUser(String username) {
        Optional<User> currentUser = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if (currentUser.isPresent()) {
            return currentUser.get();
        }
        return null;

    }
```

controller.java

```
@GetMapping("/checkUser")
public User checkUser(@RequestParam String username) {
    return userService.checkUser(username);
}
```

check.component.ts

```
checkUser() {

   this.userService.checkUser(this.username ).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.user = <User> data;
      }
    );
   console.log('user ' + this.user);
}
```

any help ??